# How authentic is the sound if I use a real effect pedal before GarageBand?

Tags: electric-guitar, effects-pedal, production, garage-band

If I consider this setup :

Electric guitar -> (real) distortion effect pedal -> audio interface -> garageband -> maybe no need to use virtual pedals from garageband

How authentic will the (real pedal) sound be?

Comment: Can you explain more about what "authentic" means to you here? The post-pedal sound is what it is. Any further change would come from the audio interface.

Comment: Real distortion effect pedals are designed to work well with the characteristics of a real amplifier's circuitry and loudspeaker.  You will likely get a very harsh tone.  I don't use GarageBand, so I don't know what amplifier simulations are available.

Comment: What effects chain are you trying to "authentically" emulate? I assume you either don't know the effects chain details or don't have all the exact equipment of some particular set up.

Answer (score 4):

*I'm gonna promote this highly opinionated comment to an actual answer…*

If you don't already own the pedal… then don't bother buying one. "Authentic" is in the ear of the beholder - if the beholder doesn't know you used a software pedal, they will never, never, ever, be any the wiser.

I've been using software amps & pedals for 20 years, & even though all the online blogs are *still* arguing over 'which is best', no-one has ever asked me if my guitars & amps are 'real'. They're not, even my guitars are software-driven. Variax, 50 guitars in one guitar.

No-one can actually tell, unless they have a camera & mic pointed at them, then suddenly they think they can… because 'likes/subscribes'.

Garage Band has the usual assortment of modelling amps & pedals, cabs & mic setups, same as most DAWs these days. I don't use GB myself, so I don't know the 'quality' of these [though bear in mind GB is the little brother of Logic, which is no slouch], but honestly, this is mature technology these days, and has been for the best part of 20 years. I very much doubt anyone would be able to tell the difference once it's in a mix. [Intro to amps and pedals in GarageBand on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/garageband/gbnd9e3c3b88/10.4.7/mac/11.5)
You *could* run a real pedal directly into GB if you have an appropriate audio interface, then route it straight through a software amp/cab/mic… I just don't really see the point.

Comment: I have a hunch that the OP may think that a typical rock/blues electric guitar sound comes from a (real or virtual) _distortion pedal_, and is unaware of what (real or virtual) guitar _amps_ and _cabinets_ do...

Comment: @Tetsujin A book, a book!    (Wait, what do you mean by "déjà-vu"?)

Comment: And if the sound is a little harsh entering the system, that's what an EQ VST plugin is for. For what its worth, I use an audio interface for some effects (with a line2amp box) and have reverted to using amp and pedals mostly for the wave of chest punching audio I can get without investing in newer expensive monitors. There is very little (no) difference between the audio interface "inserted" (bypassed or not) and only "real" pedals. IMO Real blues/rock sound comes from wah, aggressive compression with level cranked and a gain pedal (tube screamer). Gain. Lots of gain.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your pedal has a "mixer" output or "amp simulated" output, you will still need to use a guitar cabinet simulation in garageband to get a realistic guitar sound.

The direct output from these pedals is usually overly bright and harsh, as they are designed with the understanding that the sound will be muffled by the guitar cabinet at the end of the signal chain.  Luckily, there is no shortage of cabinet simulations, and your pedal will change the guitar's sound in the same way as if you were using a real amp.

As far as "authentic", "real" distortion pedals were originally just an imitation of the real distortion that comes from overdriving an amplifier.  So, to that effect, it's not really more authentic than a virtual distortion plugin on your PC.  There are some great distortion plugins available as well- look for amp sims, not just pedal sims.  I think you can find something you like.

Comment: Overdriven amps are where "overdrive" comes from, and for some really crunchy distortion, that was an accidental invention. Guitarist would accidentally break their amps, (torn speakers, busted tubes, loose wiring) and play on it anyways.  Distortion is just a sound wave getting muddled. How ot happens doesn't matter much, so long as you like the sound.

Comment: If the pedal is actually overdriving the amp input, overdriving an audio interface input is not going to sound the same even if there is a full amp simulation running behind it. But many overdrives are more distortion pedals that are inspired by overdriven tube amp than boosts that overdrive the amp vehind them.

Comment: I think you need to watch for bit clipping a little more when injecting into the virtual environment, but as long as the OP watches the levels

Answer (score 0):

It will sound authentically like the sound of 'Electric guitar -> (real) distortion effect pedal -> audio interface -> garageband'. Which you may be able to replicate with 'virtual pedals' in Garageband. Or maybe to you 'authentic' means the sound of an over-driven tube amplifier into a Marshall stack?  Does the pedal reproduce that for you in a way that makes you happy?

How many of these three methods are available to you?   Try them all!